# do not reload sidebar.php within single.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

In my Wordpress-powered website (http://onomadesign.com/wordpress/identity-design/usx-corporation/ for example) I want the `sidebar.php`, the thumbnail navigation on the right, NOT to reload when people click another project. So that they not get lost in navigation.

Now, I have looked at iframes, jQuery cookies, 'AHAH-method', php sessions.. but I can't find an easy way to do this.

I am defenitely not a programming expert, could someone give me an easy solution for this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

IFrames or AJAX are the only two options you have. (I suppose unless you did full screen flash) Everything else is going to reload the page. Ahh those other technologies you mentioned do not address the problem of reloading the main page (except iframes)

It isn't really going to be "straight-forward", but what you're trying to do isn't straight forward. I really recommend you take a look at [jQuery and how AJAX works](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/load-content-jquery-ajax-loading-image/), it's probably the better of the options all things considered.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few Wordpress plugins that attempt to implement this functionality. I haven't used any, so I'm not sure if they completely avoid reloading the sidebar, but it's worth a shot. One in particular that seems fairly well scored would be http://ajaxedwp.com/ I found this plugin by going to the "Add New" plugins page in the Wordpress Admin panel and searching for "AJAX Page Load".